# Rails Action Mailer inside loop fails after first message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send emails to a number of users, but it includes some user specific data in the rendered view, so am using a loop.

```
test_arry.each do |a|
  email = a
  name = 'john'
  encrypted = ['abc']

  NewsletterMailer.newsletter_email(email, name, encrypted).deliver
end
```

I will be using records from a database in real life but just a small array for testing. It sends the first email OK but then fails with a uninitialized constant Admin::PrivateNewslettersController::NewsletterMailer error message.